# Deferring Location Updates in Background

Tags: ios7, cllocationmanager

I have a app which collects location data in foreground and background. To save battery i want to use the allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled property as explained in [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:)
From the documents, allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled gets set(based on time and distance) in foreground. Once app goes in the background we won't receive regular location updates instead we receive them based on the  allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled.

I have implemented following code but the deferring does not get called in the background.

```
#pragma mark - Location Manager
-(void) setLocationManager
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
     NSLog(@"didUpdateLocations");

     if (!deferringUpdates)
     {
         CLLocationDistance distance = 200;
         NSTimeInterval time = 60;
    
         [locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:distance timeout:time];
    
          deferringUpdates = YES;
      }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:(NSError *)error

{
    NSLog(@"didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError");

}
```

SetLocationManager gets called in the foreground and works fine. Once app goes in the background i still receive regular location updates rather than allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled.

I have also set the following values in the info.plist file
Background Fetch
Background Location Updates
Device Capabilities - location service

Anyone luck with implementing this?

Comment: What's the value of `error` which the `locationManager:didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:` method returns?

Comment: Hey @mobiletest , have you been able to resolve the issue. If yes, will you care to share that here as correct answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to set deferringUpdates back to NO within didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError : as per Apple documentation, the "delegate’s locationManager:didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError: method is called exactly **once** for each time you call (allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled)".

Thus allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled is only called once until deferringUpdates is NO.